# Install pandas in Docker

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I've been trying to get a docker file running for three days now, but keep failing to install pandas.

Here you can see my Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
# in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the python script
COPY modbus_to_influx.py /app/modbus_to_influx.py

# Run app.py when the container launches
# The -u flag specifies to use the unbuffered output.
# in this way, what's printed by the app is visible on the host
# while the container is running
CMD ["python3", "-u", "modbus_to_influx.py"]
```

And here the `requirements.txt`

```
influxdb
minimalmodbus
numpy 
pandas
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

### I have the solution

I've used now not the python container, instead, I've used the Debian container and installed there all dependencies. This works fine now

```
# Dockerfile
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM debian:10.3-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
# in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    python3 \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-numpy \
    python3-pandas

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the python script
COPY modbus_to_influx.py /app/modbus_to_influx.py

# Run app.py when the container launches
# The -u flag specifies to use the unbuffered ouput.
# in this way, what's printed by the app is visible on the host
# while the container is running
CMD ["python3", "-u", "modbus_to_influx.py"]
```

Comment: can you try running python3 -m pip install -r requiments.txt ? might be different versions of python

Comment: What error do you get with pandas installation?

Comment: @Ioanna:I do not get an "error message", the installing build dependencies just run forever

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen: I will try it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install pandas in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190676/install-pandas-in-a-dockerfile)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer: Unfortunately not, because I've tried this solution and docker didn't collect pandas.
I've also tried to use different pandas versions (from 0.25.1 to 1.0.3) but nothing worked.
I'm a little desperate these days.

Comment: I've just tried your dockerfile and requirements file, and they worked ok for me with the latest docker updates to docker-for-windows and wsl2-ubuntu. What version of docker are you using?

Comment: `Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:35:24 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Experimental:      false`

Comment: `Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:22 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683`

Comment: Is there perhaps a problem that I want to use an raspberry for my docker?

Comment: I've added my solution into the main topic

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/77181520/6456107. Note: Different version, but the principle should be the same.